# How to get parent object based on child object fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Parent Class :

```
public class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Long id;
    List<Phone> phoneNumber = new ArrayList<>();
    int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age, Long id, List<Phone> phone) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.id = id;
        this.phoneNumber = phone;
    }
```

Child Phone object (1st level) :

```
public class Phone {
    String number;
    String type;
    Long id;
    public Phone(String number, String type, Long id) {
        super();
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch person object whose phone object type is home and its number should contain "888" in it.

```
List<Phone> list = personList.stream().map(p -> p.getPhoneNumber().stream()).
                flatMap(inputStream -> inputStream).filter(p -> p.number.contains("888") && p.type.equals("HOME")).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list.toString());
```

From above stream code, I am able to get phone object. But *how to get parent object of that phone object in that same function itself ?*.

I tried in this way and I am getting null for non-matched objects.

```
List<Person> finalList = personList.stream().map( per -> {
            List<Phone> phones = per.getPhoneNumber();
            Optional<Phone> ph = phones.stream().filter(p -> p.number.contains("888") && p.type.equals("HOME")).findAny();
        if(ph.isPresent())
            return per;
        return null;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Where I see `p.number.contains("888") && p.type.equals("HOME")` can I suggest that you use getters instead of accessing the fields directly. Additionally from a point of efficiency (although be it small) you should do your `.equals("HOME")` first because it will fail faster than `.contains("888")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Person> result = personList.stream()
    .filter( person -> person.phoneNumber.stream()
                             .anyMatch(phone -> phone.type.equals("HOME") && 
                                                phone.number.contains("888"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The thing you were looking for is `stream` of phones. It'll do the trick.

Having people with their phones, you can now remove those phones that don't match the criteria.

```
List<Person> result = personList.stream()
        .filter( person -> person.phoneNumber.stream()
                                 .anyMatch(phone -> phone.type.equals("HOME") && 
                                                    phone.number.contains("888"))
        .map(person -> {
            List<Phone> phones = person.phoneNumber.stream()
                                    .filter(phone -> phone.type.equals("HOME") && 
                                                    phone.number.contains("888"))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new Person(person.firstName, person.lastName, person.age, person.id, phones);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is really necessary a parallelStream? It may improve performance but a regular stream should work, does it? My compiler points that you are missing a parenthesis: phone.type.equals("HOME")))

Comment: @RubioRic agree.

Comment: Isn't the question 'from a collection of person objects, get some person objects that match some criteria'? What does the second part do? It seems to be making new person instances and throwing away phones for some reason. Beside being more convoluted than a loop.

Comment: @pvg The OP has accepted the answer before adding that second part and unaccepted. From his code I guess that he might also want to remove phones that don't match the criteria.